# How to manipuplate HTMLDivElement contents with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript function where i have to `add/update/remove` child div of some div. I get parent `Div's HTMLDivElement` and would like to use `jQuery` to select required child div and execute remove() (or any other jQuery function).
 Currently I cannot find how to make `jQuery` object from `HTMLDivElement`.

Am I expecting something wrong from jQuery?

**EDIT:**

The problem I'm having is that if I call $(element) I get exception:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector.
code: 12
message: "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector."
name: "SyntaxError"
stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector.↵    at Object.CommandLineAPIImpl.$ (<anonymous>:1267:41)↵    at CommandLineAPI.bound [as $] (<anonymous>:92:21)↵    at eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:3)↵    at FrameMirror.evaluate (native)↵    at Object.evaluate (<anonymous>:354:28)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:613:39)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:573:52)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:656:21)↵    at resultRender (http://host.com:3000/plugins/validate.js:5474:3)↵    at move (http://host.com:3000/scripts/bundle.js:30665:9)"
```

Comment: Can you cite an example?

Comment: Just pass the raw DOM object to jQuery. `$(div).find('selector').remove()`

Comment: First try something..! This is not a question which suit for SO's requirement..

Comment: you have not event tried anything, just look in google or jQuery docs first

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried but this does not work. Probably this is other object. Could you please at least suggest the way to tell if the object really is standard HTMLDivElement?

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `jQuery` or `$` on the `HTMLDivElement` object:

```
function removechilds(htmldiv) {
    jquery_div = $(htmldiv);
    ... use jquery_div to remove the elements you want to remove
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting exception: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Please show some example code (HTML + JavaScript) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your `div`s have `id`s, you can use jQuery selectors to target a specific one and remove it.

```
$('div#parentID div#childID').remove();
```

What the above does is that it finds the `div` with the id `childID` that has a parent that is a `div` with the id `parentID`

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of parent div elements with same class name (and children will be with the same name). I need to remove only specific. I am getting each element somewhere deep in the callback function, which forms the div cells.

Comment: I suggested using ID's rather than class names. If those are unavailable, I would suggest either grabbing all of them and then iterating through checking for matched content, or look into using `nth-child()` if you know the order.